# Consequences of not synchronizing Java collections

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, deadlock

I would like the know what are the **WORST POSSIBLE** consequences (beside data corruption) of not synchronizing a collection that is modified by multiple threads in Java.

Real example, number of threads can be larger than 10 and the collection (HashSet) can grow to around 100 000 elements (and maybe even more).

Thanks

Comment: You will end up with data which is corrupted and cannot be trusted

Comment: As to `HashMap` you may end up with a dead loop .

Comment: @passion could you explain a bit more. Is it something like an infinite loop?

Comment: @filip  http://javabypatel.blogspot.in/2016/01/infinite-loop-in-hashmap.html

Comment: *You don't have to mention that the collection will not be modified correctly, that is well known.*  Also known as, "Your data is corrupted."  What could possibly be *worse* than that?

Comment: @AndrewHenle you have a point. I need to rephrase the question

Comment: If a not synchronized collection is used in a multithreaded software that runs a nuclear power plant, many may die.

Comment: besides corrupting the data or the data structure itself, your changes could not become visible so that your code would be using stale values.

Answer (score 2):

Since HashSet uses HashMap internally, you can just look into putVal method definition of HashMap and see for yourself - at any point in execution of that method, another thread might start doing the same. It can for example catch it mid-resize, which means that data might be written to old table or two new tables will be created simultaneously.

The outcome is always data corruption, it might not even work after such incident.

Answer (score 1):

You may get `ConcurrentModificationException` if one of the threads is iterating over the set and another thread is modifying it.

The detailed explanation is in the `HashSet` documentation:

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a hash set concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the set, it must be synchronized externally. This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the set. If no such object exists, the set should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedSet method. This is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized access to the set:
>
> `Set s = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet(...));`
>
> The iterators returned by this class's iterator method are fail-fast: if the set is modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the Iterator throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.
>
> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast iterators throw `ConcurrentModificationException` on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: the fail-fast behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The worst out come is that your data structure ends up point back to itself e.g. HashMap up to Java 7 could get into an infinite loop. Thus means you get no error, rather your thread never returns.